# Instagram Oauth User Storage Period

Tags: oauth, storage, instagram, policy, user-data

How long can a developer store permission-based user Instagram data (username, friends, photos)? I'm unable to find specific documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

The [API Terms of Use](http://instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/) are a little ambiguous on this. Section 1.2

You shall not:

- Cache or store any User Content other than **for reasonable periods** in order to provide the service you are providing to Instagram users.

Your guess is as good as mine really